# create multiple htm file with different code based on csv

Tags: html, powershell, csv

I'm trying to create 50000 *.html with different content (title, Meta Description, and frame link) all of this are in a csv

in the csv have these columns (ciudad, titulo, descripcion, link)

```
$file = "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\web\full.csv"
$homepath = "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\web\html"
Import-CSV $file | ForEach-Object {New-Item -ItemType file -Path $homepath -name ($_.ciudad + '.htm')} | foreach-object  {add-content $_  @"
<title>$_.titulo</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="$_.ciudad photos">
<meta name="description" content=" $_.descripcion "> "@}
```

the files are created with the html code..but the variables in the html code are not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the two foreach-object into a single one:

```
Import-CSV $file | ForEach-Object {
  $newFile = New-Item -ItemType file -Path $homepath -name ($_.ciudad + '.htm')} 
  add-content $newFile   @"
    <title>$_.titulo</title>
"@
}
```

As the code was written the second foreach-object was getting each new file as $_, instead of getting the record from the CSV file.

I didn't try running this code so it may have syntax errors or other logic errors.

Comment: Thanks..but not work fine.

in the $_.titulo includes 

    @{link=http://www.xxx.com; titulo=xxx; descripcion=full description; ciudad=m

Comment: Run this and post the result:  `Import-CSV $file | select -first 5`

Comment: Try <title>$($_.titulo)</title>

Comment: Import-CSV $file | ForEach-Object {
$titulo = $_.titulo
$descripcion = $_.descripcion
$link = $_.link
$ciudad = $_.ciudad
$newFile = New-Item -ItemType file -Path $homepath -name ($_.ciudad + '.htm')

add-content $newFile   @"